# How to merge master to ssh

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a small simple question, since I am new to Git, I have pushed and pulled some workes, now I want to merge my master branch to my ssh repository. I mean I want to see the famous message

```
Merge branch 'master' of ssh://git.my_server.de/my_folder
```

Somewhere I found :

1. Merge that to your master with `git merge master`
2. Update your master with the result with `git push . HEAD:master`

Thank you

Comment: what's the output of this command locally: `git branch -v` ?

Comment: (detached from 048506d) 5a8f171 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://git.my_server.de/my_folder ________________________________
  master                  b1ac6b1 [behind 2] translation correction___________
  master-2                35f7107 Messages french translation

Answer (score 1):

You don't "merge" directly with remotes. When you `git pull`, what git does is :

- `git fetch` (retrieve commits from your remote to your local repo)
- `git merge` (merges those new commits with your local branch)

So you might already have done the merge. If you don't have this "Merge branch from ...", it means that git was able to do a fast forward (all it had to do was play the new commits and update the HEAD - there was no divergence).

Look at your graph with `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

Comment: what I want do is to update the remote ssh with the latest commits